# $\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\frac{\ln(\sin(x))\ln(\cos(x))}{\tan(x)}dx$

Tags: integration

I have the problem below:
$$\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\frac{\ln(\sin(x))\ln(\cos(x))}{\tan(x)}dx$$
I have tried $u=\ln(\sin(x))$ so $dx=\tan(x)du$

so the integral becomes:
$$\int_{-\infty}^0u\ln(\cos(x))du$$
but I cannot find a simple way of getting rid of this $\ln(\cos(x))$

I also tried using the substitution $v=x-\frac{\pi}{2}$
so the integral becomes:
$$\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^0\frac{\ln(\cos(v))\ln(\cos(v+\frac{\pi}{2}))}{\tan(v+\frac{\pi}{2})}dv$$
but this does not seems to lead anywhere useful

EDIT to follow up

$$B(\alpha,\beta)=\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin^{\alpha-1}(x)\cos^{\beta+1}(x)dx$$
$$\frac{\partial^2}{\partial_\alpha\partial_\beta}B(\alpha,\beta)=\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin^{\alpha-1}(x)\cos^{\beta+1}(x)\ln(\sin(x))\ln(\cos(x))dx$$
so I see that when $\alpha\to1$ and $\beta\to-1$ that this is the form that we want, so do we now have to take partial derivates of the non-integral form of the beta function then take the double integral for our chosen values?

Comment: Then you take the explicit form of $B(\alpha,\beta)$, which is given by a ratio of $\Gamma$ functions, differentiate it twice and evaluate it at the right points.

Comment: How do you take the partial derivatives of the Gamma function?

Comment: With the chain rule. $\frac{d}{dx}\Gamma(x)=\Gamma(x)\psi(x)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

\begin{equation}
 \int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\frac{\ln(\sin(x))\ln(\cos(x))}{\tan(x)}dx
 =
 \int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}
 \cos x
 \frac{\ln(\sin(x))\ln(\sqrt{1 - \sin^2 x})}{\sin(x)}dx
\end{equation}
Take
\begin{equation}
 u = \sin x
\end{equation}
so
\begin{equation}
 du = \cos x dx
\end{equation}
You get
\begin{equation}
 \int_0^1 \ln u \ln(\sqrt{1- u^2}) \frac{1}{u} du
\end{equation}
Take $u = e^v$, you get
\begin{equation}
 \frac{1}{2}
 \int_{-\infty}^0
 v \ln(1 - e^{2v}) dv
\end{equation}
Integration by parts will give you 
\begin{equation}
 \frac{1}{2}
 [\frac{1}{2}v^2 \ln(1 - e^{2v})]_{-\infty}^0
 -
 \frac{1}{2}
 \int_{-\infty}^0
 \frac{v^2}{1- e^{2v}}
 (-2e^{2v}) dv
\end{equation}
The term $ [\frac{1}{2}v^2 \ln(1 - e^{2v})]_{-\infty}^0$ is zero so
\begin{equation}
 -
 \frac{1}{2}
 \int_{-\infty}^0
 \frac{v^2}{1- e^{2v}}
 (-2e^{2v}) dv
\end{equation}
Take the following change of variable
\begin{equation}
 k = -v
\end{equation}
So we get
\begin{equation}
 \frac{1}{2}
 \int_0^{\infty}
 \frac{k^2}{e^{2k} - 1} dK
\end{equation}
Take now 
\begin{equation}
 n = 2k 
\end{equation}
as change of variable, you get
\begin{equation}
 \frac{1}{2}
 \int_0^{\infty}
 \frac{k^2}{e^{2k} - 1} dk
 =
 \frac{1}{16}
 \int_0^{\infty}
 \frac{n^2}{e^n - 1}
\end{equation}
Using the [Riemann Zeta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function)
\begin{equation}
 \zeta(x)
 =
 \frac{1}{\Gamma(x)}
 \int_0^{\infty}
 \frac{u^{x-1}}{e^u - 1}
 du
\end{equation}
or
\begin{equation}
 \zeta(x)\Gamma(x)
 =
 \int_0^{\infty}
 \frac{u^{x-1}}{e^u - 1}
 du
\end{equation}
Using the above integral for $u = n$ and $x = 3$ you will get that your integral evaluates to 
\begin{equation}
 \frac{1}{2}
 \int_0^{\infty}
 \frac{k^2}{e^{2k} - 1} dk
 =
 \frac{1}{16}
 \int_0^{\infty}
 \frac{n^2}{e^n - 1}
 =
 \frac{\overbrace{\Gamma(3)}^{2!}\zeta(3)}{16}
 =
 \frac{\zeta(3)}{8}
\end{equation}

Comment: ah I see, that is a clever method. How did you get this transformation for the zeta function?

Comment: which equation exactly ?

Comment: stating the equation for $\zeta(x)\Gamma(x)$ is this a known formula?

Comment: I have linked a reference above

Comment: Thank you thats great

Answer (score 4):

You may consider that
$$ f(\alpha,\beta) = \int_{0}^{\pi/2}\sin^{\alpha-1}(x)\cos^{\beta+1}(x)\,dx = \frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{a}{2}\right)\Gamma\left(1+\frac{b}{2}\right)}{2\,\Gamma\left(1+\frac{a+b}{2}\right)}$$
by Euler's Beta function. By applying $\frac{\partial^2}{\partial\alpha\,\partial\beta}$ to both sides, then considering the limit as $\beta\to 0$ and $\alpha\to 0^+$, we have

$$ \int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{\log\sin(x)\log\cos(x)}{\tan(x)}\,dx = -\frac{1}{12}\psi''(1) = \color{red}{\frac{\zeta(3)}{8}}.$$
By enforcing the substitutions $x\mapsto\arctan(x)$ or $x\mapsto 2\arctan(x)$ in the original integral we get interesting identities for nasty (poly)logarithmic integrals.

Comment: I have never used the Beta function but I think I understand what it is. what is this double-prime function that you state in the last line and how does the limit relate to the $\ln$ function

Comment: Here $\psi$ does not stand for the Chebyshev function. The digamma function $\psi(x)$ is defined as $\frac{d}{dx}\log\Gamma(x)=\frac{\Gamma'(x)}{\Gamma(x)}$. About the Beta function, it might be a good moment for learning its definition and typical usage: $$B(a,b)=\int_{0}^{1}x^{a-1}(1-x)^{b-1}\,dx=\frac{\Gamma(a)\Gamma(b)}{\Gamma(a+b)}.$$

Comment: can you check my edit to the question where I try this method

Comment: I now have $I=\lim_{\beta\to 0}\lim_{\alpha\to 0}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial_\alpha\partial_\beta}\left[\frac{\Gamma(\frac{\alpha}{2})\Gamma(1+\frac{\beta}{2})}{2\Gamma(1+\frac{\alpha + \beta}{2})}\right]$ but the differential of this explicit form is very complex, is there an easier way of evaluating it?

Comment: @HenryLee: not so complex if you exploit $\frac{d}{dx}f(x)=f(x)\cdot\frac{d}{dx}\log f(x)$. This is pretty practical every time a function is (implicitly) defined by a (infinite) product, Euler docet.

Comment: so is this just from $\frac{d}{dx}\ln(f(x))=\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}$?

Comment: @HenryLee: exactly. Luckily $\Gamma$ has no complex zero.