# Seeking methods to solve $ \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \ln\left|2 + \tan^2(x) \right| \:dx $

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, leibniz-integral-rule

As part of going through a [set of definite integrals](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2987994/integration-using-the-feynman-trick/3000330#3000330) that are solvable using the Feynman Trick, I am now solving the following:

$$ \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \ln\left|2 + \tan^2(x) \right| \:dx $$

I'm seeking methods using the Feynman Trick (or any method for that matter) that can be used to solve this definite integral.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If one wishes to use "Feynman's Trick," then begin by defining a function $I(a)$, $a>1$ as given by

$$I(a)=\int_0^{\pi/2}\log(a+\tan^2(x))\,dx \tag1$$

Differentiation of $(1)$ reveals

$$\begin{align}
I'(a)&=\int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{1}{a+\tan^2(x)}\,dx\\\\
&=\frac{\pi/2}{a-1}-\frac{\pi/2}{\sqrt a (a-1)}\tag2
\end{align}$$

Integration of $(2)$ yields

$$\begin{align}
I(a)&=\frac\pi2\left(\log(a-1)+\log\left(\frac{\sqrt a+1}{\sqrt{a}-1}\right) \right)\\\\
&=\pi \log(\sqrt a+1)\tag3
\end{align}$$

Finally, setting $a=2$ in $(3)$, we obtain the coveted result

$$\int_0^{\pi/2}\log(2+\tan^2(x))\,dx=\pi \log(\sqrt 2+1)$$

Comment: How did you resolve the constant of Integration in Step (3)?

Comment: @davidg Apology for the sign error.  Note $I(0)=0$.

Comment: Hi Mark ! Long time no speak. Nice solution $\to +1$. Cheers.

Comment: @MarkViola do you know of any other ‘tricks that would work?

Comment: Hi David.   You could try writing the logarithm as $\log(1+\cos^2(x))-\log(\sin^2(x))$ and expanding the first term as $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n-1}\cos^{2n}(x)}{n}$ and proceeding.   I haven't tried this, but it might be worth pursuing.

Answer (score 5):

My approach

Let

\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \ln\left|2 + \tan^2(x) \right| \:dx &= \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \ln\left|1 + \left(1 + \tan^2(x)\right) \right|  \:dx \\
&= \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \ln\left|1 + \sec^2(x) \right| \:dx \\
&= \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \ln\left|\frac{\cos^2(x) + 1}{\cos^2(x)} \right| \:dx \\
&= \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \left[ \ln\left|\cos^2(x) + 1 \right| - \ln\left|\cos^2(x)\right| \right]\:dx \\
&= \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}  \ln\left|\cos^2(x) + 1 \right|\:dx - \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}  \ln\left|\cos^2(x)\right|\:dx
\end{align}

Now

$$ \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}  \ln\left|\cos^2(x)\right|\:dx = 2\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}  \ln\left|\cos(x)\right|\:dx = 2\cdot-\frac{\pi}{2}\ln(2) = -\pi \ln(2)$$

For detail on this definite integral, see guidance [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/690644/evaluate-int-0-pi-2-log-cosx-mathrmdx)

We now need to solve

$$ \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}  \ln\left|\cos^2(x) + 1 \right|\:dx $$

Here, Let

$$ I(t) = \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}  \ln\left|\cos^2(x) + t \right|\:dx $$

Thus,

$$
 \frac{dI}{dt} = \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}  \frac{1}{\cos^2(x) + t}\:dx 
=  \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}  \frac{1}{\frac{\cos(2x) + 1}{2} + t}\:dx = 2\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}  \frac{1}{\cos(2x) + 2t + 1}\:dx
$$

Employ a change of variable $u = 2x$:

$$\frac{dI}{dt} = \int_{0}^{\pi}  \frac{1}{\cos(u) + 2t + 1}\:du $$

Employ the [Weierstrass substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution#cite_ref-3) $\omega = \tan\left(\frac{u}{2} \right)$:

\begin{align}
\frac{dI}{dt} &= \int_{0}^{\infty}  \frac{1}{\frac{1 - \omega^2}{1 + \omega^2} + 2t + 1}\:\frac{2}{1 + \omega^2}\cdot d\omega \\
&= \int_{0}^{\infty}  \frac{1}{t\omega^2 + t + 1} \:d\omega \\
&= \frac{1}{t}\int_{0}^{\infty}  \frac{1}{\omega^2 + \frac{t +  1}{t}} \:d\omega \\
&= \frac{1}{t}\left[\frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{t+1}{t}}}\arctan\left( \frac{\omega}{\sqrt{\frac{t+1}{t}}}\right)\right]_{0}^{\infty} \\
&= \frac{1}{t}\frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{t+1}{t}}}\frac{\pi}{2} \\
&= \frac{1}{\sqrt{t}\sqrt{t + 1}}\frac{\pi}{2}
\end{align}

And so,

$$I(t) = \int \frac{1}{\sqrt{t}\sqrt{t + 1}}\frac{\pi}{2}\:dt = \pi\ln\left| \sqrt{t} + \sqrt{t + 1}\right| + C$$

Now

$$I(0) = \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}  \ln\left|\cos^2(x) + 0 \right|\:dx = -\pi \ln(2) = \pi\ln\left|\sqrt{0} + \sqrt{0 + 1} \right| + C \rightarrow C = -\pi \ln(2)$$

And so,

$$I(t) = \pi\ln\left| \sqrt{t} + \sqrt{t + 1}\right| -\pi \ln(2) = \pi\ln\left|\frac{\sqrt{t} + \sqrt{t + 1}}{2} \right|$$

Thus,

$$I = I(1) = \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}  \ln\left|\cos^2(x) + 1 \right|\:dx = \pi\ln\left|\frac{\sqrt{1} + \sqrt{1 + 1}}{2} \right| = \pi\ln\left|\frac{1 + \sqrt{2}}{2} \right| $$

And Finally

\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \ln\left|2 + \tan^2(x) \right| \:dx &= \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}  \ln\left|\cos^2(x) + 1 \right|\:dx - \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}  \ln\left|\cos^2(x)\right|\:dx \\
&= \pi\ln\left|\frac{1 + \sqrt{2}}{2} \right| - \left(-\pi \ln(2)\right) \\
&=  \pi\ln\left|1 + \sqrt{2} \right|
\end{align}

Comment: Your question and your answer have a gap of just 1 minute. If you did solve the question earlier then you must've included your approach in the question itself.  What is the need to post it as an answer?

Comment: @Digamma - Sorry, although I've been a member of Math StackExchange for 4 years, I've only become regularly active recently. When I asked a friend who is a member as to what is the best way of presenting a solution whilst asking for other solutions I was told this is the approach taken within the community. If this violate any of the rules, please advise and I will reposition accordingly. Also, I never assign my solution as 'the solution' to any post of this nature.

Comment: @Digamma The site **encourages** people to share the questions with answers.

Comment: @Tianlalu - Sorry, just to be clear - Have I employed the correct process here?

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: @Tianlalu - Ta, thanks.

Comment: I like it. + 1 :)

Comment: Thanks @mick - much appreciated :-)

Answer (score 1):

$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_{0}^{\frac{k}{2}} \ln \left(2+\tan ^{2} x\right) d x=&  \underbrace{\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \ln \left(2 \cos ^{2} x+\sin ^{2} x\right) d x }_{\pi \ln \left(\frac{\sqrt{2}+1}{2}\right)} -2  \underbrace{\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \ln (\cos x) d x}_{-\frac{\pi}{2} \ln 2}\\=& \pi \ln (\sqrt{2}+1)
\end{aligned}
$$
please [refer this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4472100/732917) for the first integral.

Answer (score 1):

$$
\begin{aligned}
&\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \ln \left(2+\tan ^{2} x\right) d x\\
=&\ \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \int_0^1 \frac{\sec ^{2} x}{1+t \sec ^{2}x} dt\ dx 
=\int_0^1\frac{\frac\pi2}{\sqrt{t(1+t)}}dt = \pi \ln (\sqrt{2}+1)
\end{aligned}
$$