# Integral $\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}4} \ln(\sin{x}+\cos{x}+\sqrt{\sin{2x}})dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

> Prove that
>   $$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}4} \ln(\sin{x}+\cos{x}+\sqrt{\sin{2x}})dx =\frac{\pi}{4} \ln2$$

I tried to use King's rule and to scale by $2$ and then to add the integrals, to get product of terms and use the result $$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}2} \ln(\sin{x})dx=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}2} \ln(\cos{x})dx=-\frac{\pi}2\ln2$$
but it didnt work. Any help?

Comment: @Zacky i was experimenting with mathematica !

Comment: Standard techniques will work.

Comment: @Axion004 like what?that sqaure root is annoying...help plz

Answer (score 14, accepted):

$$I=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}4} \ln(\sin{x}+\cos{x}+\sqrt{\sin(2x)})dx =\frac12 \int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} x'\ln(\sin x+\cos x+\sqrt{\sin (2x)})dx$$
$$\overset{IBP}=\frac12 \int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}x\,\frac{\sin x-\cos x}{\sqrt{\sin(2x)}}dx\overset{x=\arctan t}=\frac{1}{2\sqrt 2}\int_0^\infty \frac{\arctan t}{1+t^2}\frac{t-1}{\sqrt t}dt$$

---

$$I(a)=\int_0^\infty \frac{\arctan(at)}{1+t^2}\frac{t-1}{\sqrt t}dt\Rightarrow I'(a)=\int_0^\infty \frac{(t-1)\sqrt t}{(1+a^2 t^2)(1+t^2)}dt$$
$$\overset{t=x^2}=\frac{2}{1-a^2}\int_0^\infty \frac{1+a^2 x^2}{1+a^2 x^4}dx-\frac{2}{1-a^2}\int_0^\infty \frac{1+x^2}{1+x^4}dx=\frac{\pi}{\sqrt 2}\frac{1-\sqrt a}{\sqrt a (1+a)(1+\sqrt a)}$$

---

$$\Rightarrow I=\frac{\pi}{4}\int_0^1 \frac{1-\sqrt a}{\sqrt a (1+a)(1+\sqrt a)}da\overset{\sqrt a=x}=\frac{\pi}{2}\int_0^1 \frac{1-x}{(1+x^2)(1+x)}dx=\frac{\pi}{4}\ln 2 $$

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: Yeah its clear!

Comment: A question. Why did the bounds of integration change in the first step? How is the coefficient 1/2 justified?

Comment: @TheCoolDrop if we consider $f(x)=\ln(\sin x+\cos x+\sqrt{\sin(2x)})$ then notice that:
$$\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} f(x)dx=\int_0^\frac{\pi}{4} f(x) dx +\int_\frac{\pi}{4}^\frac{\pi}{2} f(x) dx$$
Now let $\frac{\pi}{2}-x =t$ and notice that $f(\pi/2-t)=f(t)$ to get:
$$\int_\frac{\pi}{4}^\frac{\pi}{2} f(x) dx =\int_0^\frac{\pi}{4} f(t) dt\Rightarrow \int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} f(x)dx=2\int_0^\frac{\pi}{4} f(x) dx $$

Comment: Very elegant solution, for sure.

Comment: @Zacky in the comment above, why does $f(\frac{\pi}{2}-t)=f(t)$?

Comment: @Axion004  Plug in $f(t)=\ln(\sin t+\cos t+\sqrt{\sin(2t)})$ the followings: $\sin(\pi/2-t)=\cos t$, $\cos (\pi/2-t)=\sin t$ and $\sin(\pi-2t)=\sin(2t)$.

Comment: Ah, I see. This makes 

$$\int_{\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}f(x)dx =\int_{\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}f(\frac{\pi}{2}-t)dt = \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}f(t)dt$$

Comment: But, then again as $\frac{\pi}{2} - x = t ~\Rightarrow ~ x = \frac{\pi}{2} - t$, shouldn't the upper bound be switched to $x = \frac{\pi}{2} - t = \frac{\pi}{2}$ or $t=0$ and the lower bound is switched to $\frac{\pi}{4}$?

Comment: With the substitution $\frac{\pi}{2}-x=t\Rightarrow dx=-dt$ we get:
$$\int_\frac{\pi}{4}^\frac{\pi}{2}f(x)dx=\int_\frac{\pi}{4}^0 f\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-t\right)(-dt)=\int_0^\frac{\pi}{4} f\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-t\right)dt$$

Comment: I see, sorry I haven't done this in a while and am extremely rusty.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a different solution using complex method. We can notice that

\begin{align*}
I = &\int_0^{\frac \pi 4} \ln\left(1+\tan x + \sqrt{2\tan x} \right) dx + \int_0^{\frac\pi 4} \ln(\cos x) dx \\
= &I_1 + I_2.
\end{align*}
**Evaluation of $I_1$ :** Let $\displaystyle\omega = e^{\frac {\pi i} 4} =\frac{1+i}{\sqrt 2}$ and make substitution $\tan x= y^2 $ to find that
\begin{align*}
I_1 =& \int_0^1 \log\left((1+\omega y)(1+\bar \omega y)\right)\frac{2y }{1+y^4}dy  \\
=& 4 \Re \int_0^1 \frac{y \log\left(\frac{1+\omega y}2 \right)}{1+y^4} dy +\frac {\pi\ln 2}2.
\end{align*} Let $\omega y = z$. Then using $\omega^2 = i, \omega^4 = -1$, 
\begin{align*}
\Re \int_0^1 \frac{y \log\left(\frac{1+\omega y}2 \right)}{1+y^4} dy =& \Re \int_0^\omega \frac{ \frac{z}{\omega} \log\left(\frac{1+z}{2}\right)}{1+ (\frac z \omega)^4} \frac{dz}\omega \\
=& \Im \int_0^\omega \frac{z \log\left(\frac{1+z}{2}\right)}{1-z^4} dz \\
=& \frac 1 2 \Im \int_{-\omega}^\omega \frac{z \log\left(\frac{1+z}{2}\right)}{1-z^4} dz.
\end{align*} Note that $\displaystyle f(z) =  \frac{z \log\left(\frac{1+z}{2}\right)}{1-z^4} $ is analytic in $|z|<1$, and continuous in $|z|\le 1$ except at points $\displaystyle -1, \pm i$. So by choosing a contour $z = e^{i\theta}, -\frac \pi 4\le \theta \le \frac \pi 4$ and using $\log(1+e^{i\theta}) = \log\left(2\cos\left(\frac \theta 2\right)\right) + \frac {i\theta}{2}$, etc, we get
\begin{align*}
\Im \int_{-\omega}^\omega \frac{z \log\left(\frac{1+z}{2}\right)}{1-z^4} dz =&\Im \int_{-\frac \pi 4}^{\frac \pi 4} \frac{ie^{i2\theta}\left(\log(\cos (\theta/2)) + i\theta/2\right)}{1-e^{i4\theta}} d\theta\\
=&-\Im  \int_{-\frac \pi 4}^{\frac \pi 4} \frac{\log(\cos (\theta/2)) + i\theta/2}{2\sin(2\theta)} d\theta\\
=& -\frac 1 4\int_{-\frac \pi 4}^{\frac \pi 4} \frac{\theta}{\sin(2\theta)} d\theta\\
=& -\frac 1 4 \int_{0}^{\frac \pi 4} \frac{\theta}{\sin\theta \cos \theta} d\theta\\
=:& -\frac 1 4 J
\end{align*} (In fact $J = G$, the Catalan's number.) This gives
$$
I_1 = -\frac 1 2 J +\frac {\pi \ln 2}2.
$$

**Evaluation of $I_2$ :** By integrating by parts, we have
\begin{align*}
I_2 =& x\ln(\cos x)|^{\frac \pi 4}_0 +\int_0^{\frac \pi 4} \frac {x \sin x}{\cos x} dx \\
=&-\frac{\pi \ln 2}{8} +K.
\end{align*} We observe that
\begin{align*}
K-J = & -\int_0^{\frac \pi 4} \frac{x\cos x}{\sin x} dx\\
=& -x\log(\sin x)|^{\frac \pi 4}_0 + \int_0^{\frac \pi 4} \log(\sin x) dx\\
=& \frac{\pi \ln 2}{8} + \int_{\frac \pi 4}^{\frac\pi 2} \log(\cos x) dx \tag{$\frac \pi 2 - x\mapsto x$}\\
=&-\frac{3\pi \ln 2}{8} -I_2
\end{align*} thus $\displaystyle K = -\frac{3\pi \ln 2}{8} -I_2 +J$ and 
$$
I_2 = -\frac{\pi \ln 2}{2} -I_2 +J \Longrightarrow I_2 = \frac 1 2 J -\frac{\pi \ln 2}{4}.
$$ Therefore, we have
$$
I = I_1 + I_2 = \left(-\frac 1 2 J +\frac{\pi\ln 2}2\right)+\left(\frac 1 2 J -\frac{\pi \ln 2}{4}\right) = \frac {\pi \ln 2}4.
$$

Comment: Wow! Amazing one! Thanks a lot!

Comment: I hope it was helpful! :)

Comment: It was helpful :)